# implementing mask functionality using BitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, bitmapdata

I have two BitmapData objects with transparency enabled. One is a large red square, the other is a small blue circle.

If, for example, I position the blue circle over the red square. I would like to create an area of transparency in the red square's BitmapData where the blur circle is. Similar to how a mask works.

I have tried using getPixel32() operations but it is very slow (see below). Is there another way I can do this? Thanks

```
for(var x:int = 0; x < circleBitmapData.width; x++){
   for(var y:int = 0; y < circleBitmapData.width; y++){
       if(circleBitmapData.getPixel32(x,y) != 0x00000000){
           squareBitmapData.setPixel(x,y,0x00000000);
        }
   }
}
```

EDIT - I have one possible solution, but it's not ideal. I can merge the two bitmaps, then use the `threshold` method to turn pixels above a certain value to transparent. So I could set all blue pixels to transparent. However, I get a thin ring of blue around the transparent area

Comment: Why can't you use a mask?

Comment: Because I'm doing blitting

Answer (score 0):

Check out bitmapData's threshold method. It should return you a bitmapData with the intersected area. With that, you don't have to get and set pixel anymore. Also, getPixel32 should have setPixel32 :P

Comment: I can't find a difference method. The closest I can see is the compare method? but that wouldn't work

Comment: user1063998 upload your project somewhere and I will take a look for you mate. leave a comment here with my name so i'll get a notification when you do.